# SSL certificates that work out of the box server side

Tags: ssl

I have a GoDaddy SSL certificate and certain other server side scripts are hitting the endpoints.

We're stumbling unto the problems fixed by this https://github.com/coolaj86/node-ssl-root-cas, where the GoDaddy root certificate is not installed by default.

What certificate should I get so users won't run into this problem? The goal is not have them install ca-certificates or weird hacks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to install the appropriate intermediate certificate, chaining your certificate back to a root certificate that's installed in the user's browser. You should go to [this page](https://certs.godaddy.com/anonymous/repository.pki), download the certificate bundle that's appropriate for your certificate, and then install the bundle in your web server -- how you do that depends on what web server it is, which you haven't specified.

Comment: That's already been done. It's working properly everywhere except server side callbacks.

Comment: Again, there are github node projects for working around this issue.  I just want to know what certificate to buy at an affordable price because apparently cheap-o ones don't work so debs don't have to make ugly hacks.